# How to prepare query parameters in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Coming from a background in PHP/CodeIgniter where running queries is as simple as...

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', array(
    $userId
));
```

I'm trying to accomplish something similar with Java.  I know running straight queries can be as simple as...

```
    TypedQuery<Guest> query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT g FROM Guest g ORDER BY g.id", Guest.class);
    return query.getResultList();
```

But how do I inject parameters into the queries?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to skim over this: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use either named parameters or positional parameters.

**Named parameter**
 `SELECT g FROM Guest g WHERE g.name = :name`

Then you can write this on your query reference:
`query.setParameter("name", aName)`

**Positional parameter**
`SELECT g FROM Guest g WHERE g.name = ?1`

Then you can write this on your query reference:
`query.setParameter(1, aName);`